# Mocha: Hide console.log output from successful tests

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, console.log

## My Problem

I'm writing a test suite for a Node.js application using [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/). The functions that I'm testing write their logs to `console.log` directly, without any third-party logging solution.

I don't care about logs from successful tests, just from failed tests, and since my functions are pretty verbose the test output is unnecessarily long.

## What Have I Tried

- SFTW. Found this ([Suppress console log of successful mocha tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449000/suppress-console-log-of-successful-mocha-tests)), but it refers to Winston logs.

## My Question

How can I suppress `console.log` output from passing / successful Mocha tests?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can modify the `console.log` function to log its argument to a variable:

```
const originalLogFunction = console.log;
let output;
beforeEach(function(done) {
  output = '';
  console.log = (msg) => {
    output += msg + '\n';
  };
});
```

```
afterEach(function() {
  console.log = originalLogFunction; // undo dummy log function
  if (this.currentTest.state === 'failed') {
    console.log(output);
  }
});
```

You might need to modify the dummy log function in case you are supplying more than one argument or objects. This is a simplified example.

Answer (score 15):

This is utterly simple with [Mocha Suppress Logs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-suppress-logs).

Just install it:

```
npm install --save-dev mocha-suppress-logs
```

and EITHER add it to your Mocha command:

```sh
mocha --require mocha-suppress-logs
```

OR put this in your Mocha config to make it the default:

```
"require": "mocha-suppress-logs"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using `sinon`

Another [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53102024/369707) (currently accepted as of this posting) can be refactored to use the `sinon` [stubbing library](https://sinonjs.org/), like so:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');

let consoleOutput;  

beforeEach(function () {
  consoleOutput = '';
  sinon.stub(console, 'log').callsFake((msg) => {
    consoleOutput += msg + '\n';
  });
});

afterEach(function () {
  sinon.restore();
  if (this.currentTest.state === 'failed') {
    console.log(consoleOutput);
  }
});
```